# Get Multiple checkboxes in cakephp mail template

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Created View as

```
<?php $options = array("Eng_yes" => "English", "teg_yes" => "Telugu", "hin_yes" => "Hindi"); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('read', array(
    'label' => __('Read', false),
    'type' => 'select',
    'multiple' => 'checkbox',
    'options' => $options,
)); ?>
<?php $options = array("Eng_yes" => "English", "teg_yes" => "Telugu", "hin_yes" => "Hindi"); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('write', array(
    'label' => __('Write', false),
    'type' => 'select',
    'multiple' => 'checkbox',
    'options' => $options,
)); ?>
<?php $options = array("Eng_yes" => "English", "teg_yes" => "Telugu", "hin_yes" => "Hindi"); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('understand', array(
    'label' => __('Understand', false),
    'type' => 'select',
    'multiple' => 'checkbox',
    'options' => $options,
)); ?>
```

Created Controller as

```
public function enquiry_form()
{
    App::uses('CakeEmail', 'Network/Email');
    $useremail = $this->data['Feedback']['email'];
    $read = $this->data['Feedback']['read'];
    $write = $this->data['Feedback']['write'];
    $understand = $this->data['Feedback']['understand'];
    $Email = new CakeEmail();
    $Email->template('enquiry_form')
        ->subject($usertopic)
        ->to('xyz@xyz.com')
        ->from($useremail)
        ->viewVars(array('read' => $read, 'write' => $write, 'understand' => $understand))
        ->emailFormat('both')
        ->send();
    $this->Session->setFlash(__('Your Feedback has been sent'), 'flash', array('alert' => 'success'));
    $this->redirect($this->referer());
}
```

Email Template File

```
<?= $read ?>
<?= $write ?>
<?= $understand ?>
```

When I sent a mail using this code, In mail body getting

> Notice (8): Array to string conversion [APP/View/Emails/html/enquiry_form.ctp, line 1]
>   Code Context

```
<p><?=$read ?></p>
$viewFile = '/code/app/View/Emails/html/enquiry_form.ctp'
$dataForView = array(
'useremail' => 'test@gmail.com',
'read' => array(
    (int) 0 => 'teg_yes'
),
'write' => array(
    (int) 0 => 'teg_yes'
),
'understand' => array(
    (int) 0 => 'teg_yes'
)
)
```

How do I display check-boxes values in mail body.

Comment: You are trying to print `array` as `string` in your `enquiry_form.ctp` file.

Comment: Please can you share the code of APP/View/Emails/html/enquiry_form.ctp ?

Comment: This is the code in my enquiry_form.ctp
<?= $read ?>
<?= $write ?>
<?= $understand ?>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to print array as string in your enquiry_form.ctp template file. Use like this.
Email Template File

```
<?= $read[0] ?>
<?= $write[0] ?>
<?= $understand[0] ?>
```

Hope this will solve your issue.